# Using Excel TextJoin in conjunction with a Countifs() with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to return a comma separated list of strings, based on a match within two tables, BUT with a conditional criteria.

Below you will see what I mean. 
[image]

And my formulas:
PlayerNames:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B4=teamRecs,playerNames,""))}
```

## Players:

```
=COUNTIF(teamRecs,B4)
```

## Signed:

```
=COUNTIFS(teamRecs,B4,K4:K13,"y")
```

My Issue is that I would like to return the list of PlayerNames, **only if they have been signed**. -- Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark as I don't have `TEXTJOIN` but something along these lines possibly? `{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(I4:I13=1, IF(J4:J13="y",H4:H13,""),""))}` Notice to enter as array formula.

Comment: Formula looks OK but looking at your formula  B4 must be A4

Comment: @jvdv answer was spot on. Thanks. If you make it an answer, I'll flag it. Only thing missing is the else "" for the second IF.  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment, you could try:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(I4:I13=1, IF(J4:J13="y",H4:H13,""),""))}
```

Enter as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Shame I don't have `TEXTJOIN` myself to test it, even though I have Excel 2016 :(